# Laravel 5.7 many to many sync() not working

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have a intermediary table in which I want to save `sbj_type_id` and `difficulty_level_id` so I have setup this:

```
$difficulty_level = DifficultyLevel::find(5);
if ($difficulty_level->sbj_types()->sync($request->hard, false)) {
    dd('ok');
}
else {
    dd('not ok');
}
```

Here is my **DifficultyLevel.php:**

```
public function sbj_types() {
     return $this->belongsToMany('App\SbjType');
}
```

and here is my **SbjType.php:**

```
public function difficulty_levels() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\DifficultyLevel');
}
```

In the above code I have `dd('ok')` it's returning **ok** but the database table is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
return $this->hasMany('App\DifficultyLevel');
```

to

```
return $this->belongsToMany('App\DifficultyLevel');
```

The `sync()` method takes an array with the id's of the records you want to sync as argument to which you can optionally add intermediate table values. While `sync($request->hard, false)` doesn't seem to throw an exception in your case, I don't see how this would work.

Try for example:

```
$difficulty_level->sbj_types()->sync([1,2,3]);
```

where `1,2,3` are the id's of the `sbj_types`.

You can read more about syncing [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Dont forget that you can also add properties to each id on the sync table too if you need.

Comment: Thanks it's working can you tell me what's the reason to change `hasMany` to `belongsToMany`

Comment: You can use `hasMany` for a one to many relation. When the relation is many to many, there is (technically) no model that "owns" the other model, that's probably why `belongsToMany` is used in this case, on both models. A linguistic approach to define table relationships can be hard to understand in some cases.